# Slow Execution Time

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have a request to add new column that will count distinct column named kode_buatan from january to the month in the record (so if the record have date in march 2024 count distinct kode buatan from january 2024 to march 2024) so i made this query

```
WITH coba1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM table_A
)
SELECT coba1.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT kode_buatan) 
   FROM table_A sd 
   WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM coba1.date) 
     AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM coba1.date) 
     AND sd.shipto = coba1.shipto) AS calculated_column_name
FROM coba1;
```

then there is problem that the data is duplicate so i add distinct and it turn the execution time so long (unfinished). can someone give me some advice to increasing performance of the query? thank you

I have tried

```
WITH coba1 AS (
  SELECT * FROM table_A
)
SELECT coba1.*, 
  (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT kode_buatan) 
   FROM table_A sd 
   WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM coba1.date) 
     AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM coba1.date) 
     AND sd.shipto = coba1.shipto) AS calculated_column_name
FROM
```

and

```
create table coba2 as (
select extract(year from date) as TAHUN, extract(month from date) as BULAN, shipto, (select count(distinct kode_buatan) from salesout_doi sd where extract(month from sd.date) <= extract(month from coba1.date) and extract(year from sd.date) = extract(year from coba1.date) and sd.shipto = coba1.shipto ) from salesout_doi_cobaaaytd coba1 where extract(year from date) = 2024
)

select distinct * from coba2
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that stuff and I think your query is false...

Try :

```
SELECT coba1.*, COUNT(DISTINCT kode_buatan) AS calculated_column_name
FROM   table_A AS sd JOIN table_A AS coba1
       ON sd.shipto = coba1.shipto
       AND (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(YEAR FROM coba1.date) 
            OR (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM sd.date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM coba1.date)
                AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM sd.date) <= EXTRACT(MONTH FROM coba1.date) )
GROUP  BY coba1.*
```

Replace "coba1.*" by the exact enumeration of the column's name...

A way to have more performance would by to add a computed column in the table with the concatenation of year an mont, in the form : YYYYMM

Comment: i tried your query but it think for joining 2.5 billion with it self to much space required my dbeaver tells this

SQL Error [53100]: ERROR: could not write to file "base/pgsql_tmp/pgsql_tmp509003.203": No space left on device

Comment: @Andika_Nurtamin, sorry I made a mistake in the query I give to you. The first predicate member after the OR logical connector must be compare with  an equal not a <=. I rewrite the query... Did you try with a computed column in the tables ?

Comment: @Andika_Nurtamin, On the other hand, be aware that PostGreSQL is not designed for large volumes, high complexity or a large number of accesses. Indeed PostGreSQL does not know how to do multithreaded queries, compression on tables and indexes, nor automatically manage its different caches, nor use vertical indexes (columnar)... All things which strongly optimize the aggregation operations and the GROUP BY... I wrote many paper about that to compare PG to SQL Server : http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-sql-server-mssql-part-3-very-extremely-detailed-comparison/

Answer (score -1):

First check whether there is any Index for Column kode_buatan.
If there is no index, you should create a new index for that column.

Also recommended to Use Display Execution Plan to do a better optimization of your query.

Comment: I have make it, but it still takes time. fyi the data is about 2.5million in the table

Comment: May be the fragmentation for that index is too high. If The fragmentation of that is over 30, you should rebuild it (Online Rebuild your operational Index). (in your case it must be over 95). I had same problem and rebuild index and also Statistics solved the problem.

Comment: I checked select distinct in my PC on an index with 2.1 million rows. it takes 0 seconds. it shouldn't takes long.

Comment: if just select distinct i think it will perform well but as you can see i have subquerries that i used in there maybe its the one that cause slow?

Comment: and i check in some blog that i should not worry because i use postgresql